# Wordpress how to get field from parent category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, advanced-custom-fields

I'm trying to display an image in a custom field on child category archive pages.

The current setup is:

```html
<?php
    $term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;
    $post_id = 'product_cat_'.$term_id;
    $custom_field = get_field('brand_background', $post_id);
?>

<div id="brandHeader" class="brand-header-logo" style="background-image: url('<?php the_field('brand_background', $post_id); ?>');">
```

This obviously gets the 'background image' field from the category archive it's currently on.

If the category is a child category I want to be able to pull the 'background image' from the parent category. I've tried a few things but doesn't seem to be working - can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `get_ancestors` function to get the `parent id` and use that id to get your field:

> [get_ancestors](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_ancestors/)

So let's say your categories looks like this:

-Parent (id = 24)
--Child (id = 42)

```php
$term_id = get_queried_object()->term_id;

$term_ancestor_ids = get_ancestors($term_id, 'product_cat');

// if you do a print_r on $term_ancestor_ids
// you'll see this: 
// Array ( [0] => 24 )

$post_id = 'product_cat_'.$term_ancestor_ids[0];

$custom_field = get_field('brand_background', $post_id);
```

Tested and works, let me know if you were able to get it to work too!

Comment: Thank you that did work - is there simple way to check if there are ancestors first? My parent categories now aren't showing background images and would be good to make it "if has ancestors then use the ancestor id else use the normal category id"

Comment: if (empty($term_ancestor_ids)){
 $post_id = 'product_cat_'.$term_id;
}else{
$post_id = 'product_cat_'.$term_ancestor_ids[0];}